# function not working properly in chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a function that's working correcty in Firefox, but failing in chrome. It's supposed to open a test window, and **IF** successful, close the test and redirect the parent. I'm still getting into java. I understand there are differences in how browsers interpret JS, just not sure why in this instance, chrome is redirecting the parent window even if the child "testWindow" is not created (e.g.). I'd apprecitate your comments

thanks 
Gillian

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindow(){
    testWindow =    window.open("popup.php","interaction");
    if(testWindow){ 
        setTimeout(function() { testWindow.close(); },1000);
        setTimeout(function() { window.parent.location = "http://www.google.com"; },1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Failing in chrome means? What it doesn't do in chrome?

Comment: it is redirecting the parent window even if the object testWindow is not created

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your javascript in chrome, it opens a window, then close it and redirect you to goole. I think it's worked as intended. Can you be more precise about your problem ?

BTW, I think windo.open returns null if there was an error, so maybe you should change your if condition to `(testWindow !== null)` to avoid some browser compatibility problems.

Comment: I want to build a test the informs the user that their browser is blocking popups. I have a test window that opens. if successful it closes and re-directs the parent window. If the test window fails I want the parent window to NOT be redirected - does that make sense